# What runs first in an AngularJS app? (module, config, run, etc.)

Tags: angularjs

I am curious about the way I am structuring my app (I'm probably wasting time on things that don't matter), but curiosity leads me to ask nonetheless.

In AngularJS, how does an app work? For example, if I have this code in app.js (removed my implementations, just showing the structure):

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app', ['ui.router', 'satellizer', 'permission', 'angular-jwt', 'ui.bootstrap', 'angular-loading-bar'])
        .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$authProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', Config])
        .run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$auth', 'jwtHelper', 'Permission', Run]);

    function Run($rootScope, $state, $auth, jwtHelper, userService, Permission) {
        // Some code
    }

    function Config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $authProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
        // Some code
    }

})();
```

.. what runs first? I'm curious because I want to know if I should place `run` before `config`, and so on. I don't want config to load but be waiting on `run` to do something, when it would be more efficient to have `run` first so there is no waiting..if that's even a problem to begin with.

Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#!/.  Configuration happens first, then the run block occurs.  During configuration and during the run phase, injectables  are restricted, to prevent accidental instantiation of unconfigured services, and to prevent further system configuration, respectively.

Comment: Just a note, it doesn't matter in which order you register `config` and `run`, as @Claies wrote, `config` will always run first.

Comment: you were so close to reach an answer by yourself... just remove the aditional things that aren't required and using a degenerated (simple) example adding some console.log() inside the functions and whatever logs first execute first, like this => https://jsfiddle.net/Lby1janq/

Answer (score 5):

When bootstrapping, first AngularJS applies all constant definitions. Then AngularJS applies configuration blocks in the same order they were registered.

src: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#!%2F

---

**Order Of Call**

1. `app.config()`
2. `app.run()`
3. Directive's compile functions if they are found in the DOM.
4. `app.controller()`

src:https://gxbsst.gitbooks.io/angularjs-foundations/config_vs_run.html

Answer (score 4):

From the official Angular documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#!/)

"Run Blocks

Run blocks are the closest thing in AngularJS to the main method. A run block is the code which needs to run to kickstart the application. It is executed after all of the services have been configured and the injector has been created."

(the 'config' is configuring services that are being instantiated using the 'provider' method)

Answer (score 2):

First it will config and then run will be executed

Comment: Care to explain your reasoning?  An assertion with no explanation carries very little educational value.