# Angular 2: What is the bootstrap process?

Tags: angular

I have looked through the documentation and I can't find anything on the step by step process of what happens during bootstrap.

I'm looking for something along the lines of this:

1. All modules are collected
2. Providers are instantiated and put into the injector for respective modules
3. Components, Directives and Pipes
4. ...

I looked at the source on the [Angular GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular), however I could not find the implementation of the `platformBrowserDynamic.bootstrapModule(AppModule)` (which I assume would detail the process). That directory is located [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/packages/platform-browser-dynamic), but `bootstrapModule` is nowhere to be found.

If someone could explain this to me, or if someone could link me to the source of the bootstrapping process, it would be highly appreciated!

Comment: this is a very very broad topic with very little information on the web, you can try asking several more specific questions

Comment: Take a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34258533/what-runs-first-in-an-angularjs-app-module-config-run-etc) I had about AngularJS 1.x from 2015 on. As you can see, there was a clearly defined process insofar as what happens step by step in the [bootstrap process](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#!%2F), at least for the first couple of steps. I am looking for some similar guidance.

Comment: well, I tried to put up a high level of operations in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44530026/2545680)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing you have to understand is that APIs related to application bootstrap are currently under review. Here is the very high level order of operations.

These lines:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
```

1. Create the platform with root injector (platformBrowserDynamic)
2. Use the platform to bootstrap the module (bootstrapModule)

When module is being bootstrapped (this section is skipped if you're using AOT):

1. Create a JIT compiler
2. [Compile](https://angular.io/api/core/Compiler#compileModuleAsync) AppModule and all its components - [create factories](https://hackernoon.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e)
3. Bootstrap AppModule factory

When boostrapping AppModule factory:

1. Create NgZone injector
2. Create AppModule instance (moduleRef)
3. Boostrap components specified in `bootstrap` in AppModule

Which means:

1. Create bootstrap component instance - creates component views for all child components (Services.createRootView) and instantiates component/directive classes. I believe this is the most important step as Angular here goes recursively through the factories created for all components by compiler and creates views. It also creates DOM nodes and attaches them to each other.
2. Attach the created root component view to the applicationRef
3. [Run change detection](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f) which triggers all lifecycle hooks on components

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer! One question: are all services (`@Injectable()`'s) instantiated BEFORE any components are, at least at a module level? I am asking because I want to create a permissions directive which will use a service, and in that services constructor on page load I want to run some init code to create a map in memory so that the map can be used at the component level from the directive, and I just want to make sure that the service constructor has run before any directives try to access it from a component.

Comment: Sure, you're welcome. A service instance just before it's being injected, not when its found in the module. So if you register a service in providers and never inject it anywhere, no instance of it will be created

Comment: @Lansana, is there else missing in my answer so you can accept it?